# ellipsis: ten to eighty thousand dollars

Tags: ellipsis

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) This antique vase is worth **ten thousand to eighty thousand** dollars. **(NO ELLIPSIS)**

(2) This antique vase is worth **ten** to eighty thousand dollars. **(ELLIPSIS used)**

Question: in (2), with "thousand" omitted from "ten", would it be understood as "ten thousand"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to repeat words like "thousand“, ”million“ or ”billion“](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/347710/when-to-repeat-words-like-thousand-million-or-billion)

Answer (score 2):

If the range were 10 to 80,000 the phrasing would be different.

> This antique vase is worth ten dollars to eighty thousand.

Which basically means "I have no idea" and an antiques trader would not have such ignorance of its worth. So

> This antique vase is worth ten to eighty thousand dollars

would be readily understood as meaning 10,000 to 80,000.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

"*This antique vase is worth ten to eighty thousand dollars*" is an ambiguous statement. It could mean either that the range starts at ten (10) or ten thousand (10,000). But we deal with ambiguities all the time using *common sense*. For example, if someone said "*my dad travels to work in his hat*" would you think his hat was his vehicle? Of course not. So, what would someone think of your statement? If the range started at ten, that's a pretty big range. I'd seriously question the credibility of any antiques 'expert' who valued something anywhere between a tenner and eighty grand.